# How does Google App Invites for iOS download the app and then open the deep link?

Tags: ios, google-play, app-store, deep-linking

I'm looking at the [details of the iOS app store](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1633/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009414), and don't see any way to tell the app store to open a deep link after installation.

The [flowchart for Google App Invites](https://developers.google.com/app-invites/ios/) seems to do this very thing.  How does Google accomplish this?

[image]

Is it using something other than the App Store?